# How to check if the first child of a div is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check with jquery if the first child of my div has the class active or not. But i can't figure it out can someone help?

Here is my code:

```js
$(".popup .title:first-child")
if ($this == .active) {
  console.log("class is active");
} else {
  console.log("class is not active");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
  <h3 class="title active"></h3>
  <h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: just use `hasClass`. `$(this).hasClass("active")`

Comment: When/how often do you want to run this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($("div h3:first-child").hasClass(".active")){
 console.log("Class is active");
}
```

Comment: Think you're missing a bracket

Comment: The first `"` should be replaced with `)`. Cannot do that, because edits must be at least 6 characters long, lol.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a function, `hasClass()` to check whether an element has a class. In this case:

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  console.log("class is active");
} else{
  console.log("class is not active");
}
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can check if the child has class `active` -

```
if($(".popup .title:first-child").hasClass('active')){
  console.log("class is active");
} else{
  console.log("class is not active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// True
console.log( 
    $( ".popup .title" ).first().hasClass('active')
);

// True
console.log( 
    $( ".popup .title:nth-child(1)" ).hasClass('active')
);

// False
console.log( 
    $( ".popup .title:nth-child(2)" ).hasClass('active')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
<h3 class="title active"></h3>
<h3 class="title"></h3>
</div>
```